# How does ORMlite manage inheritance between Java classes?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, orm, ormlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I properly annotate inheritance classes using ORMLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290207/how-do-i-properly-annotate-inheritance-classes-using-ormlite)

I am new on ORMlite and I'm trying to figure out how ORMlite works with inheritance.

What I have:

3 java classes, which have one common property. Every class should be a DatabaseTable.

What I need:

Update the common property one shot for every table, letting ORM does it for me, avoiding to update every table by me.

Is there a way to do that?